# issue on mapView annotationView calloutAccessoryControlTapped

Tags: ios, google-maps, mkannotationview

I have this problem:

In my App I use this very simply code:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
       self.mapPopup.hidden=false;
    }
```

This code on the iOS 6 version of my App works great.... on the same app for iOS7 when I tap 2 times, the App crash.

The error that came out is "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

I've also noted that in ios6 don't makes any distinction from left touch or right touch (on the annotation)... in ios7 yes!

I must manage differents touches (left & right)?

For better understand...
I've a stuff like this:
[image]

If i click over blue button, all works fine (the app open a detail view).
When I close the opened view, if I tap over the text (ie. "Current Location") my app crashes

Answer (score 1):

I apologize
I made a big mistake: I've used this code:

```
[rightButton addTarget:self:@selector(mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

for to specify the action, but this executes the code twice... Probably the cause of the crashes!!!

Problem solved!!! :D Thanks iRD for your attention..

Answer (score 0):

Have you used diddeselectmethod for annotation view?

I was too facing the same issue when i was selecting any annotation view :

i just added hide and show in the didDeselectannotation view method :

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

     customAnnotationView.hidden=NO;

    if (_calloutAnnotation&& ![view isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotationView class]]) {
        if (_calloutAnnotation.coordinate.latitude == view.annotation.coordinate.latitude&&
            _calloutAnnotation.coordinate.longitude == view.annotation.coordinate.longitude) {

            [customAnnotationView setHidden:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the console log and code you are using so that i can figure it out the exact error by which your are getting EXC BAD EXC

Comment: Not goes... your method is called when I click on the map (outside the pin) but my problem is when i tap inside (in the middle) of the pin. All works fine if I tap the left button that I've created.... Is so strange... into IOS6 is perfect!!! :|

Comment: Just check where its crashing by Symbolic and Exceptional breakpoints and using NSZombieEnabled argument in schemes